# Generate Entity Framework Query with multiple OR-Statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tuples

Currently I have a List (`List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>)` representing a list of time ranges.
Now I want to create a generic list where I select all records that are within these ranges.

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> ranges = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>{
    new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime(new Date(2018,01,01), new Date(2019,01,01)}

IQueryable<item> items = context.items.Where(e => e.category.equals("somecategory"));

ranges.ForEach((Tuple<DateTime, DateTime) range => { 
     items = items.Where(e => e.date >= range.Item1 && e.date <= range.Item2); 
})
```

The last loop should extend the statement with "OR" so that I have

```
.Where(e => e.date between range1 || e.date between range2 || ...).
```

Is there any clever solution for that?

Comment: Do you want to select all items that there is one or more ranges that item's range is between that range?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809542/joining-multiple-where-clauses-in-linq-as-or-instead-of-and/3809609

Comment: I want to select all items where the date is within one of the given ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my restrictions that our Entity Framework version cannot handle tuples, I solved the issue using `Union`:

```
public List<MyObject> GetList(Item item){
    IQueryable<MyObject> qMyobjects = this.GetQueryableList(item, item.ranges.first().item1, item.ranges.first().item2;

    item.ranges.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach((Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> range) => {
        IQueryable<MyObject> select = this.GetQueryableList(item, range.item1, range.item2);
        qMyobjects = qMyobjects.Union(select);
    });
    return qMyobjects.ToList();
}

protected IQueryable<MyObject> GetQueryableList(Item item, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo){
    return _context.myobjects
        .Where(e => e.category.Equals("somecategory")
        .Where(e => e.date >= dateFrom && e.date <= dateTo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Tuple` can directly use inside `Where` clause like

```
var result = (from i in items
              from r in ranges
              where i.date >= r.Item1 && i.date <= r.Item2
              select i).ToList();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm interpretting that wrong, but doesn't this query with ```contains``` only filters for tuples that are similar? I need to filter for items where the date is between that date range.

Comment: let me check it out again :)

Comment: @SNO, in above update query i get the data from database within both range of date in list of tuple.

Comment: Thank you for that solution. Unfortunatly I get a "System.NotSupportedException". Maybe it's because of using a tuple in combination with our Oracle-Database.

Comment: @SNO, Is perfectly works on my machine with sql server maybe you can try it with sql server. Its your choice that If my answer was helpful to you then you can mark tick on left side of answer to make it green and vote up also

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't change my database and so this solution doesn't work for me. But the coding looks great. So I give it my vote :)

Answer (score 0):

You should Dynamically create lambda expressions using Expression,for example：

```
List<Person> totalPerson = new List<Person> {
    new Person{  Id = 1,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,2)},
    new Person{  Id = 2,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,3)},
    new Person{  Id = 3,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,4)},
    new Person{  Id = 4,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,6)},
    new Person{  Id = 5,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,7)},
    new Person{  Id = 6,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,8)},
    new Person{  Id = 7,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,11)},
    new Person{  Id = 8,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,12)},
    new Person{  Id = 9,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,13)},
    new Person{  Id = 10,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,16)},
    new Person{  Id = 11,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,17)},
    new Person{  Id = 12,CreateTime = new DateTime(2018,10,18)}
};
List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> ranges = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>{
    new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2018,10,1), new DateTime(2018,10,5)),
    new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2018,10,10), new DateTime(2018,10,15))
};

IQueryable<Person> persons = totalPerson.Where(t => t.Id > 0).AsQueryable();
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "t");
BinaryExpression binaryExpression = null;

ranges.ForEach(range =>
{
    MemberExpression filed = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "CreateTime");
    var startTime = Expression.Constant(range.Item1);
    var endTime = Expression.Constant(range.Item2);
    var expressionItem1 = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(filed, startTime);
    var expressionItem2 = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(filed, endTime);
    var expressionItem = Expression.And(expressionItem1, expressionItem2); ;
    if (binaryExpression == null)
    {
        binaryExpression = expressionItem;
    }
    else
    {
        binaryExpression = Expression.Or(binaryExpression, expressionItem);
    }
});
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameter);

var results = persons.Where(condition);
```